# How comment out a variable line in a local variable list

Tags: comment, file-local-variables

In a python file I have

```
# Local Variables:
# python-shell-interpreter: "python3"
# python-shell-virtualenv-path: "~/.virtualenvs/datascience"
# leo-python-args-to-send: "-f fqanalysis.txt"
# End:
```

For a couple of days I want to use the python file without the specified virtualenv, so I would like to *comment out* the line setting `python-shell-virtualenv-path`, so that next time I open the python file in emacs `python-shell-virtualenv-path` keeps its global value.

I tried

```
# ;;python-shell-virtualenv-path: "~/.virtualenvs/datascience"
```

and

```
## python-shell-virtualenv-path: "~/.virtualenvs/datascience"
```

but on opening the python file I always get the error

```
File mode specification error: (error "Malformed local variable line: ...)
```

How do I comment out the local variable line correctly?

Comment: When I select the line containing `# python-shell-virtualenv-path: "~/.virtualenvs/datascience"` and apply the command `comment-region`, the result is `# # python-shell-virtualenv-path: "~/.virtualenvs/datascience"`. I don't know if it is the correct way to comment out local variables.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Based on a quick check of <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>g</kbd> `(emacs) Specifying File Variables`, I'm reasonably sure that you can't.

I think your options are:

- Move the comment outside of the local variables block.
- Change the variable (e.g. give it a prefix like `DISABLED:`) such that the value is simply assigned to a variable which nothing uses.

Edit:

If you don't want to have to approve a bunch of `DISABLED:foo` variables for `safe-local-variable-values`, you could adapt the approach to take advantage of the fact that successive entries clobber earlier ones if the same variable name is used.  Something like:

```
# Local Variables:
# #: python-shell-interpreter: "python3"
# #: python-shell-virtualenv-path: "~/.virtualenvs/datascience"
# leo-python-args-to-send: "-f fqanalysis.txt"
# #: <comment>
# End:
```

These still aren't comments, but it does mean you only have a *single* local variable named `#` (or `\#` in this instance) with the value `<comment>`, and Emacs won't query you about the earlier ones; so you could re-use this approach in other files and only end up with a single `safe-local-variable-values` entry for all such 'commented' values, so long as that `#: <comment>` entry always comes last.

(YMMV; this is only lightly tested, and is obviously a hack workaround.  Note also that you needn't use the actual comment character, as it's actually a variable name, so you can call it whatever you want, so long as it's not likely to conflict with any 'proper' variable name.)

You could ditch the need for a `#: <comment>` entry but still avoid being asked questions if you added the following to your config:

```
(put '\# 'safe-local-variable (lambda (_) t))
```

Which says "ALL values for the variable `#` are safe.